# clearInterval not working on a specific occasion (javasripct, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where I set an interval on a button press and try to clear it when the button is pressed again. I also have it set up so that the interval is set when user leaves the page and when he comes back, the interval should get cleared.(I am using a pause plugin, so .pause() and .resume() are a thing). This is the javascript code:

```
var check
var pauseactive
function pause() {
    $('.box').pause();
    $('#pauseimg').attr('src','buttonimg.png');
    $('#pause').attr('ID','resume');
    check=setInterval(pausecheck,10);
    pauseactive=1;
}
function resume() {
    $('.box').resume();
    $('#pauseimg').attr('src','pause.png');
    $('#resume').attr('ID','pause');
    window.clearInterval(check);
    pauseactive=0;
}
$(document).on('click','#pause',pause);

$(document).on('click','#resume',resume);

$(window).blur(pause); //this is also surrounded by $(document).ready()

$(window).focus(resume); //this is also surrounded by $(document).ready()
```

EDIT (better explanation):
When I click the `#pause` button, it does what it's supposed to do. When I then click the `#resume` button, it clears the interval correctly.
When I leave the page, the `pause` function activates correctly and when I come back, the `resume` function acts as it should and clears the interval.
The problem comes when I click the `#pause` button and then leave the page. After that when I come back, the function doesn't clear. Could that be because it's doing the `setInterval` twice?

Comment: What are you expecting `$('.box').pause` to do? Because all you're doing is accessing a property, not doing anything with it.

Comment: That is pausing all of the animations that .box is currently doing. So what I want to happen is the .box to stop animating when I press the button (it's a pause button)

Comment: Not as of my comment above it wasn't. Now that you've added the `();`, perhaps it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing between `pause` and `resume`? Coz the code of `clearInterval` and `setInterval` needs to be swapped:

```
function pause() {
    $('.box').pause(); // Give the (); here.
    $('#pauseimg').attr('src','buttonimg.png');
    $('#pause').attr('ID','resume');
    window.clearInterval(check);
    pauseactive=1;
}
function resume() {
    $('.box').resume();
    $('#pauseimg').attr('src','pause.png');
    $('#resume').attr('ID','pause');
    check=setInterval(pausecheck,10);
    pauseactive=0;
}
```

You forgot to call the function. Instead it just refers to the `pause` function. That has been corrected.

So once the `pause()` is invoked, the interval should be cleared. That has been swapped now. Please check.

Comment: No, I'm sorry is the explanation wasn't clear enough there, but the interval is supposed to get set when the pause function is fired, I have that set up correctly because it works, the only problem is when the interval is set by the button press and then I leave the page and come back, in that scenario the interval doesn't get cleared as it should.

Comment: @PavelPochobradsky Did you try changing your first line to `$('.box').pause();` instead of `$('.box').pause`

Comment: Yes I did, in fact, I just forgot to copy it into here. Will edit now.

Comment: @PavelPochobradsky Okay, now can you fix all the errors like semicolon missing on each line and tell what's happening? Update your question too.